# Proving an $m\times n$ matrix has left and right inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be and $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n\times m$ so that $AB=I_m$ and $BA=I_n$.  Need to show that $m=n$.  Now I thought I could just show that $AB=BA$.  The way I approached this problem is the following:  $$AABB=ABAB \Longrightarrow (BA)ABB=(BA)BAB$$ $$I_nABB=I_mBAB \Longrightarrow I_nAB(BA)=I_nBA(BA)$$ $$I_nABI_n=I_nBAI_n\Longrightarrow I_nABI_n=BA.$$  I have noticed several problems with this though specifically $AABB$ because $$AABB=A(AB)B=AI_mB$$ since $A$ is $m\times n$ and $I_m$ $m\times m$ they can not be multiplied similarly for $B$ $n\times m$. Also for $I_n$ times $A$ and $B$ times $I_n$.  I have also tried $BBAA=BABA$ and run into a similar problem.  Any help would be appreciated.